# How to replace x in the pattern with the given number?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

What I have tried yet...

```
 <?

$dataArry = array (
"aab"=> array(
    "mobile"=>'123456789',
    "country"=>"Antigua and Barbuda",
    "countryCode"=>"+1-268",
    "pattern"=>"3#4",
    "pattern2"=>"(xx)-xxxxxxx"
)
);

$data = $dataArry["aab"]["mobile"];    //  number with leading 0...

if ($data[0] == "0" ) {  //remove the leading 0 from number...
    $data = substr($data, 1); 
}

$pattern = $dataArry["aab"]["pattern2"];
echo preg_replace("([x]+)", $data, $pattern);

?>
```

I'm getting a result as `(123456789)-123456789` but I want the result
 like  `(12)-3456789`

Actually, I want to convert all the mobile numbers in number format according to that country so, I am saving a pattern with the country in my database. so, I can convert them later when I need to display it...

previously I was using this code but it not more dynamic because format can be like `(12) 44 33 222, or 12 44 33 22`. so I thought of saving patterns like (xx) xx xx xxx, xx xx xx xx and replace all x with the number. the number of x will always be the same for the x in the pattern.

```
<?
$match = "";

$dataArry = array(
    "ind" => array(
        "mobile" => '07505942189',
        "country" => "india",
        "countryCode" => "+91",
        "pattern" => "3#3#4"
    ),
    "us" => array(
        "mobile" => '3784001234',
        "country" => "US",
        "countryCode" => "+1",
        "pattern" => "3#3#4"
    ),
    "aab" => array(
        "mobile" => '4641234',
        "country" => "Antigua and Barbuda",
        "countryCode" => "+1-268",
        "pattern" => "3#4"
    ),
    "afg" => array(
        "mobile" => '0201234567',
        "country" => "Afghanistan",
        "countryCode" => "+93",
        "pattern" => "2#7"
    )
);
$result .= $dataArry["afg"]["countryCode"] . " ";
$data = $dataArry["afg"]["mobile"]; // indian number with leading 0...
if ($data[0] == "0") { //remove the leading 0 from number...
    $data = substr($data, 1);
}


$string = $dataArry["afg"]["pattern"]; // pattern code 

$string = explode("#", $string); //making array of string pattern code.

foreach ($string as $vals) {
    $match .= "(\d{" . $vals . "})";
}

//if(  preg_match( '/^\+\d(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})$/', $data,  $matches ) )
if (preg_match("/" . $match . "/", $data, $matches)) {
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($matches); $i++) {
        if ($i == 1) {
            $result .= "(";
        }
        $result .= $matches[$i];
        if ($i == 1) {
            $result .= ")";
        }

        if ($i < count($matches) - 1) {
            $result .= "-";
        }



    }
    echo $result;
}


//research https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_telephone_prefixes_by_country
//research http://www.onesimcard.com/how-to-dial/

?>
```

Comment: I see no leading zero in your sample mobile number.  Maybe you should tell us what you are trying to accomplish in general here.  Is `(12)` a country code or prefix?  What would happen with numbers from other countries?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen okay I am going to edit and will give more explaination...

Comment: Note it is more readable to use non-paired regex delimiters, e.g. `"/x+/"`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is it more understandable now?

Comment: How long can those numbers be?

Comment: it is contact number so, they will not be more than 12 I think...

Comment: You would have done better to just show us a wide sample of input numbers, along with how you want them to look in the output.  Right now, I see a big mess of PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to accomplish it:

```
$mobile = '123456789';
$pattern = '(xx)-xxxxxxx';

echo preg_replace_callback('/x+/', function ($match) use (&$mobile) {
    $length = strlen($match[0]);

    $replacement = substr($mobile, 0, $length);

    $mobile = substr($mobile, $length);

    return $replacement;
}, $pattern);
```

https://3v4l.org/9QCD6

Comment: nice work, will it work for all patterns like xxx xxx xxxx? number of  x will always be same with number of digits but pattern can be different... 

Thanks